# como funciona la ejecución del cron en laravel

Tags: laravel, cron

Una vez creado el respectivo *cron* con su funcionalidad podemos asignarle un tiempo, que la documentación dice que es su "tiempo de ejecución"

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('cron:job')
             ->everyMinute();
}
```

Para ejecutar el schedule de laravel el servidor necesita de igual forma un *cron* o tarea programada.

Entonces, cual es la función del tiempo definido **`->everyMinute()`** si realmente el cron que se ejecutará por el lado del servidor disparará la ejecución de nuestro schedule, ya que nuestro schedule de laravel no tiene un comportamiento como una *queue* (Se ejecuta una vez un comando y queda operativo).

Si yo defino el tiempo de mi *cron* del lado del servidor a 1 hora, mi schedule de laravel se ejecutaría cada 1 hora, no cada 1 minuto como lo he definido dentro del schedule.

Comment: el cron del server le dice al queue del laravel cada un minuto que procese la cola de trabajos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea del cron de laravel, es que tu creas dentro de tu **schedule**, todos lo cron jobs que se van a ejecuten en los tiempos indicados, y que en el ***servidor solo tengas que crear un cron jobs***, el cual se ejecutara cada minuto, disparando tu schedule, el cual se encargara de administrar los corn de tu aplicación y **determinara en que momento se debe ejecutar cada cron**.

Con esto no tienes que crear mas de un cron en tu servidor para disparar cada una de las tareas que necesites ejecutaren tu aplicación.